# How to print the repo project and shortstat with git repo forall command?

Tags: git, repo

With repo forall command, how to print both `shortstat` and `REPO_PROJECT`?

I tried below, it didn't work, it just prints the `$REPO_PROJECT` but not the `shortstat`.

```
repo forall -c 'echo $REPO_PROJECT' -c 'git diff --shortstat tagA tagB'
```

I wanted it to print:

```
project/name
1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

there is a `-p` option to print project name

```
repo forall -p -c 'git diff --shortstat tagA tagB'
```

In my project, this command output something as follow:

```
project MTCommonServices/
 9 files changed, 274 insertions(+), 216 deletions(-)

project MTConfig/
 2 files changed, 12 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)

project MTModuleOrder/
 26 files changed, 764 insertions(+), 160 deletions(-)

project MTModuleProductDetail/
 8 files changed, 34 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)

project MTModuleUser/
 18 files changed, 444 insertions(+), 148 deletions(-)

project MaitaoApp/
 3 files changed, 137 insertions(+), 111 deletions(-)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19752891)

Comment: @Clijsters I believe my answer is a solution for this question.

Comment: It's ok, down here in germany, you can believe what you want. As OP says he's missing the shortstat, and not the project name, I believe you are wrong.

Comment: @Clijsters I'd say a bad answer is still an answer. That's what votes are for. Flags are for other cases, like people posting follow-up questions as answers, etc.

Comment: @anothernode: This is not a bad answer, it is in fact not an answer to the question. It says something completely different and would beter fit as a comment.

Comment: @Clijsters Maybe I have some mis-understanding of `shortstat`. From the question's description, I think `shortstat` means something like `9 files changed, 274 insertions(+), 216 deletions(-)`? I've added a sample output in my answer, please check if it is correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
repo forall -c 'echo $REPO_PROJECT; git diff --shortstat tagA tagB'
```

works.

Comment: The key here is to use single quote `'` around the evaluated command, so `$REPO_PROJECT` is expended for each repo projects.  
If double quotes `"` are used, then `$REPO_PROJECT` is expended before evaluating `repo forall` command, which has not the expected effect.

Answer (score 0):

repo forall -c 'git status | dos2unix'
works